# cifs permission denied with docker-compose run but not docker-compose exec

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cifs

I have a script that mounts a cifs share.

When I run `docker-compose run www ./myscript` mount returns

`mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)`

When I run `docker-compose up -d www && docker-compose exec www ./my-script` It can mount the cifs share.

My docker-compose.yml looks like

```
version: "3"
services:
  www:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./www.dockerfile
    environment:
      - SAMBA_USER
      - SAMBA_PASS
      - SAMBA_PATH
      - SAMBA_MASK
    volumes:
      - ./www:/app
    cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
      - DAC_READ_SEARCH
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    command: tail -f /dev/null # hang container so I can exec in
```

my www.dockerfile looks like

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN apt install -y cifs-utils
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./www /app
```

www/myscript looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /mnt/data
mount -t cifs -o username=$SAMBA_USER,password=$SAMBA_PASS "$SAMBA_PATH" /mnt/data
ls /mnt/data
```

Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24

docker-compose version 1.20.1, build 5d8c71b

I really want ./myscript to run as the docker-compose command, but it also returns permission denied.  Any clues? TIA

Comment: It fails on ubuntu 14.04 but not docker-for-mac

Comment: I've got a repo that demonstrates the problem. git clone https://github.com/lukerohde/debug-cifs-on-docker-compose.git && cd debug-cifs-on-docker-compose && ./run-test

Comment: I've cross posted on docker-compose's github https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5958

Comment: Both cases fail in newer versions of docker for mac too.  Must be a capabilities change.

Answer (score 2):

In my case in addition to `--cap-add SYS_ADMIN --cap-add DAC_READ_SEARCH` I have to disable (better write your own template) apparmor template because default docker apparmor template has `deny mount` directive.

For example

```
docker run -it 
    --cap-add SYS_ADMIN 
    --cap-add DAC_READ_SEARCH 
    --security-opt="apparmor:unconfined" 
    my-container
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 'privileged: true' in my compose file worked, but felt evil.

I tried a bunch of random capabilities from this list https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities but couldn't find any combo that would work (wasn't systematic).

Decided against using samba in the end.